# Does Rexcel work for Excel 2013?

Tags: r, vba, rexcel

I followed the instructions from http://homepage.univie.ac.at/erich.neuwirth/php/rcomwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:how_to_install step by step and installed the Rexcel for my Excel 2013, I found the GUI interface doesn't appear in Excel. And I tried the VBA code from their example document as below:

```
Sub RexcelDemo()
    RInterface.StartRServer
    RInterface.GetRApply "sin", _
        Range("A2"), Range("A1")
    RInterface.StaopRServer
End Sub
```

It does not work and yellow bug indicator appeared in the second line.
I am very confused about : does Rexcel really work for Excel 2013?
If not, is there any other API we can find to replace it as a connection server between R and Excel?

Comment: did you correct the typo at the last line in your code ? `StopRServer` instead of `StaopRServer`

Comment: There are many interfaces with R: [RDOMClient](http://www.omegahat.org/RDCOMClient/) and even [RScript.exe](http://www.r-bloggers.com/passing-arguments-to-an-r-script-from-command-lines/) at command line where R can accept parameters and run as subprocesses in other languages. What do you need to do?